# VueJS Google places autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vue.js, google-places-autocomplete

Hi guys Im having an error implementing the google autocomplete.
So here's the scenario [image: On the blue its working fine but when I replace it to the red its not working]
On the blue its working fine but when I replace it to the red its not working
[image: result]
Now when I put it on the line where the red arrow points I got this error
[image]

For reference Im using this: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-autocomplete
I also tried this one
https://medium.com/dailyjs/google-places-autocomplete-in-vue-js-350aa934b18d

Its working fine but when I put it on the loop its not working. It seems 
the mounted state got an error. Here's the code of my mounted()

```
//this is the current I used
this.$refs.address.focus();
//this is for the 2nd one
/*this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (this.$refs.autocomplete),
      {types: ['geocode']}
    );
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
      let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      let ac = place.address_components;
      let lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
      let lon = place.geometry.location.lng();
      let city = ac[0]["short_name"];

      console.log(`The user picked ${city} with the coordinates ${lat}, ${lon}`);
    });*/
```

Comment: Can you post your code for `WorkHistory.vue`? The whole thing

Comment: @RuChernChong please get here. I cant add here sorry thanks
http://jsbin.com/vaduzucoyo/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line inside your `mounted` with this:

`if(this.$refs.address) this.$refs.address.focus();`

Because the autocomplete component is placed inside `v-for` so when the `WorkHistory.vue` component is mounted, it doesn't know what `this.$refs.address` is, unless `work_history_data` has at least 1 item.